# RTK createListenerMiddleware saga channels

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, redux-saga

I'm using RTK createListenerMiddleware in my project, I was wondering if there's a recipe for Redux-saga like channels pattern.
I'm referring to this Saga pattern:

```
import { channel } from 'redux-saga'
import { take, fork, ... } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* watchRequests() {
  // create a channel to queue incoming requests
  const chan = yield call(channel)

  // create 3 worker 'threads'
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    yield fork(handleRequest, chan)
  }

  while (true) {
    const {payload} = yield take('REQUEST')
    yield put(chan, payload)
  }
}

function* handleRequest(chan) {
  while (true) {
    const payload = yield take(chan)
    // process the request
  }
}
```

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels/#using-channels-to-communicate-between-sagas

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Redux maintainer and [I created the listener middleware](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2022/03/designing-rtk-listener-middleware/).

We designed the listener middleware to do *almost* all the things that you could do with sagas: listen for actions, pause, cancelation, and even forking off "child tasks".

However, we intentionally did *not* reimplement *everything* that sagas could do, to save on complexity and bundle size.  Channels are a saga capability that we chose to not mimic in the listener middleware.

It's possible you could do something sorta-similar yourself in some way, but there's definitely nothing built into the listener middleware API that is similar to channels.

Comment: could be a good idea for npm package